# python string manipulation, finding a substring within a string

Tags: python

I am trying to find a substring within a larger string in python. I am trying to find the text present after the string "Requests per second:" is found. It seems my knowledge of python strings and python in general is lacking.

My error is on the 3rd line of code `minusStuffBeforeReqPer = output[reqPerIndx[0], len(output)]`, I get the error that without the `[0]` on reqPerIndx I am trying to access a tuple, but with it I get the error that I `int object has no attribute __getitem__`. I am trying to find the index of the start of the reqPerStr in the `output` string.

The code

```
#output contains the string reqPerStr.
reqPerStr = "Requests per second:"
reqPerIndx = output.find(reqPerStr)
minusStuffBeforeReqPer = output[reqPerIndx[0], len(output)]
eolIndx = minusStuffBeforeReqPer.find("\n")
semiColIndx = minusStuffBeforeReqPer.find(":")
instanceTestObj.reqPerSec = minusStuffBeforeReqPer[semiColIndx+1, eolIndx]
```

Comment: I get the feeling this isn't the best way to do this. If you're trying to find a substring that appears after a known substring, you should use regex lookbehinds.

Comment: the find() method returns an integer representing an index. You are attempting reqPerIndx[0], which makes no sense.

Comment: If you look to the right of your question on this page, you will see a column of related questions. Some of them have the answers you seek. The same list would have come up while you were writing your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use `output[begin:end]`, not `output[begin, end]` (that's just how the syntax for slicing ordinary strings/lists/etc works). So:

```
minusStuffBeforeReqPer = output[reqPerIndx:len(output)]
```

However, this is redundant. So you should instead probably do this:

```
minusStuffBeforeReqPer = output[reqPerIndx:]
```

By omitting the `end` part of the slice, the slice will go all the way to the end of `output`.

---

You get a error about accessing a tuple without the `[0]` because you have passed a tuple (namely `(reqPerIndx, len(output))` to the slicing `[...]`), and you get an error about `int` having no `__getitem__` because when you write `reqPerIndx[0]`, you are trying to get the `0`th element of `reqPerIndx`, which is an integer, but there is of course no such thing as the "0th element of an integer", because integers do not have elements.

---

As @AshwiniChaudhary points out in the comments, `str.find` will return `-1` if the substring is not found. If you are certain that the thing you're looking for will always be found somewhere in `output`, I suppose you don't need to handle the `-1` case, but it might be a good idea to do so anyway.

```
reqPerIndx = output.find(reqPerStr)
if reqPerIndx != -1:
    minusStuffBeforeReqPer = ...
    # etc
else:
    # handle this case separately
```

---

You might have better luck with regexes. I don't know what `output` looks like, so I sort of just guessed - you should adapt this to match whatever you have in `output`.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'(?:Requests per second:)\s*(\d+)', "Requests: 24")
[]
>>> re.findall(r'(?:Requests per second:)\s*(\d+)', "Requests per second: 24")
['24']
```

Comment: Note that `str.find` returns -1 for missing sub-strings, that should be handled as well.

Comment: I never thought of using regex, I'm not that well versed in it. But the given regex code, how does it read (find string "" and return ..)?

Comment: Take a look at http://regex101.com/r/aX9yI6 - it might help. Basically, the `(?:...)` means "look for `...` but don't capture it (i.e. return it in output)". The `\s*` means "look for any amount of whitespace". Finally, `(\d+)` means "look for one or more digits, and capture it (i.e. return it in output)".

Answer (score 0):

You have the error on those two lines:

```
minusStuffBeforeReqPer = output[reqPerIndx[0], len(output)]
instanceTestObj.reqPerSec = minusStuffBeforeReqPer[semiColIndx+1, eolIndx]
```

You have to use the `:` to create a range. `start:end`.

You can omit the last parameter to get to the end or omit the first parameter to omit the begining. The parameters can be negative number too. Since find might return `-1` you'll have to handle it differently because if the string isn't found, you'll end up with:

```
minusStuffBeforeReqPer = output[-1:]
```

Which is the last char in the string.

You should have code that looks like this:

```
#output contains the string reqPerStr.
reqPerStr = "Requests per second:"
reqPerIndx = output.find(reqPerStr)
if reqPerIndx != -1:
    minusStuffBeforeReqPer = output[reqPerIndx[0]:]
    eolIndx = minusStuffBeforeReqPer.find("\n")
    semiColIndx = minusStuffBeforeReqPer.find(":")

    if eolIndx > semiColIndx >= 0:

        instanceTestObj.reqPerSec = minusStuffBeforeReqPer[semiColIndx+1:eolIndx]
```

This is good but, you should definitely change the code with a regex. As I understand, you really want to match a string that starts with `reqPerStr` and ends with `\n` and get everything that is in between `:` and `\n`.

You could do that with such pattern:

```
"Requests per second:(.*)\n"
```

You'll end up with:

```
import re

reqPerIndx = output.find(reqPerStr)

match = re.match("Requests per second:(.*)\n", output)
if match:
    instanceTestObj.reqPerSec = match.group(1)
```

If you want to find all matches, you can do that:

```
for match in re.finditer("Requests per second:(.*)", output)
    instanceTestObj.reqPerSec = match.group(1)
```